Getting Process ID of Windows Terminal after using Process.Start(Cmd)
I start at TShark process via Process.Start(), but I want the new console window minimized. I don't want it hidden in case the parent program crashes, leaving a hidden TShark process recording indefinitely.
I have been using ShowWindow(TsharkProc.MainWindowHandle), which works great when the old Command Prompt is used.
When the new Windows Terminal App is set as the default console app, the MainWindowHandle is 0, preventing ShowWindow() from being effective.
I don't think this is a bug, due to the nature of Windows Terminal acting as a wrapper for multiple processes, at least one per tab.
For now, I am just getting the list of Windows Terminal processes by name: Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsTerminal") and minimizing each that is found. This works, but I'm curious if there is a better way to minimize the Windows Terminal window that contains the TShark process.

it seems you should be able to start new process with window minimized by passing ProcessStartInfo to Process.Start.
// Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes,
    // both in a minimized mode.
    void OpenWithStartInfo()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-8.0
Process.Start also returns Process, from which you can get Id or MainWindowHandle that can be used to further interact with window - reference.

I have tried the StartInfo.WindowStyle, but it doesn't seem to have an effect, using Minimized or Hidden. I did forget that Process.Start() returns the new process, I'll give that a shot.
